# Does the LiveCount of Session include session from memory to memory replication in websphere?

Tags: websphere, websphere-7, websphere-6.1

i can see the **LiveCount** and **ActiveCount** of session from Websphere TPV. As for the websphere cluster environment in which that memory-to-memory replication enabled, does that LiveCount of session here include the session of backup copy from other application server?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe the related mbean queries the store without caring how the session got into the local store. However, you must probably have push policy towards the server enabled to have copies of all the sessions available. Otherwise you will have only the count for the accessed sessions (accesses with pull policy asks the other server for copy).